# How do I use an OR clause in a COUNTIFS formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This formula works, but it'd be simpler with an OR statement in there somewhere...

> =COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$J:$J,"=HNT",'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&Q$4,'Sheet1'!$AA:$AA,"<"&$A$2-2,'Sheet1'!$AC:$AC,"=")+COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$J:$J,"=HNT Fuel",'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&Q$4,'Sheet1'!$AA:$AA,"<"&$A$2-2,'Sheet1'!$AC:$AC,"=")

Comment: Edited my answer to offer a useful solution (not involving `OR`, but working nonetheless).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are thinking of `OR`ing the two criteria “HNT” and “HNT Fuel”, I am very much afraid that is not possible: `OR` doesn’t return anything of use to `COUNTIFS`. However, the `COUNTIF` and `SUMIF` formulas will [accept an array of criteria](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showpost.php?s=86bb9faad4e6009ec5c9c5cd1f63f62d&p=1342197&postcount=4), outputting an array of results, which you can sum up.

The following formula gets rid of the repetition and is extensible to allow for more variants:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!$J:$J,{"HNT","HNT Fuel"},
              'Sheet1'!$A:$A,"="&Q$4,
              'Sheet1'!$AA:$AA,"<"&$A$2-2,
              'Sheet1'!$AC:$AC,"="))
```

Note you do not need the `=` when comparing a string literal for equality (there are gotchas as to cell data to string conversion when you use a cell reference, but not with literals).

Comment: Edited after stumbling over Colin Legg’s superb [`SUMIF` Workshop](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=310600).